# Running an external JavaScript code in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs

I want to run an external JS which is actually opencv.js. I need to access its CV variable and then calling other functions.

I am adding below codes to my `useeffect` hook as follow:

```
export default function PolygonCropper(props) {
      ...
      useEffect(() => {
    
        const script = document.createElement("script");
        script.src = "https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.0/opencv.js";
        script.async = false;    
        document.body.appendChild(script);
        //
        console.log('cv from opencv is');
        console.log(window["cv"]);
        ....
    
       }
```

However, I can't access window["cv"] and it is undefined when I look at logs in chrome.

EDIT:

looking at Chrome log by console.log(window). I can see the window and CV inside it but I can access window["cv"]
[image]

Comment: Why are you trying to add the script to the document every time the component mounts?  That should be a static `script` tag.  And why _would_ it be attached to the window?  You don't have any code here that would make it global.

Comment: I guess the correct way is to put that in useffect to avoid duplicate injections. I editted my question, when I console.log(window) I can see cv inside it.